# Spotify turns into "Google Assistant" and crashes

Tags: root-access, magisk, google-assistant, spotify

This is a weird one - I'm running Magisk rooted Lineage on a Pixel 4a

When I reboot, Spotify is renamed to Google Assistant and I get a popup saying "Google Assistant keeps stopping", and Spotify (Google Assistant with the Spotify logo) won't launch.
Clearing cache and storage doesn't fix it, I have to uninstall and reinstall, and then it'll work perfectly until I reboot.
Just today it stopped renaming but it still gets bricked, so I did some more investigating:

- I un-rooted and the problem stopped happening, then re-rooted and it started again.
- I turned everything off in the Superuser tab of Magisk, and removed all my modules (Except SafetyNet Fix) but it still happens
- The problem started around when I installed ReVanced so I've completely removed everything related (Youtube ReVanced, Youtube, Revanced Manager, and related modules) but no luck
- If I let Spotify get bricked then un-root ("Restore Images" from Magisk, not "Complete Uninstall"), Spotify works fine. So it seems like something is interfering with it, rather than modifying the installation

Comment: Which safety net are you using? Don't use Kdragons but [Displax's](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-mod-universal-safetynet-fix.4553699/)// I don't think that it's the source of your problem and you haven't mentioned in your question if you are using magisk deny list, which is a sub-optimal root hiding solution. Use [Denylist Unmount module](https://github.com/mywalkb/DenylistUnmount). Remember to configure Spotify in Magisk but **do not** enforce deny list for the said module to work

Comment: Thank you, yes I've got Displax's USF. I haven't had any problem with the stock denylist but I'll check out the Unmount module if I need it later

Comment: I suspect (maybe wrong) that root detection by Spotify is causing this. To rule this out try the suggested module or Shamiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a "Complete Uninstall" from Magisk, then re-rooted and it's fixed the issue even after reinstalling everything I had. Maybe it was a virus of some kind ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
If you have any other theories or have a similar experience let me know